# Cross-compile Windows Executable on Linux host

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I've looked all over the internet trying to find out, but I can't find it. Can you compile programs for windows on a Linux machine?
Info:
I am using Gcc in it's newest version(I just updated it)
I am trying to compile a program I wrote in C.
I am trying to compile for an Intel Core2 Quad Q9550 processor

Please help if you can. I'm not sure if there is a tag you can add to gcc to do it or something, but thank you for any help you can give!

**EDIT:** I'm trying to compile for a 32-bit Windows machine

Comment: Yes, the MinGW tool chain is available as a cross-compiler that can run on Linux and produce binaries for Windows. Example tutorial: http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

Comment: the specific model does not matter much. the target OS matters a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my search didn't go very far...first link in google now. [MinGW](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIpYus5-DQAhXos1QKHQf4A2MQFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blogcompiler.com%2F2010%2F07%2F11%2Fcompile-for-windows-on-linux%2F&usg=AFQjCNF69uThLAxKLHOM52tcaYWYCPpz1Q&sig2=IFD-MWdPnFL28mumXSAWYw)